# PROC IML - Matrix as frequency crosstab

Tags: sas, crosstab

I need to prepare a cross-table using PROC IML (I know it’s more usual to use PROC FREQ in such cases but this is for the school project and they forced us to use IML).

Data set looks like:

A ORANGE 
B APPLE 
C ORANGE 
B MANGO 
B APPLE

And the output should have ORANGE APPLE MANGO in columns, A B C in rows and the frequency in the matrix, basically:

ORANGE APPLE MANGO
A 1 0 0 
B 0 2 1 
C 1 0 0

**Edited to add:**

I'm moving closer to the solution but still have some problem with selecting the rows which meet certain criteria - "(...)" in code. Below you can find what I came up with:

```
PROC IML;
USE work.data;
    read all var {fruits } into fruits;
    read all var {names} into names;
    read all var {fruits names} into matrix;
close;
u1 = unique(fruits);
u2 = unique(names);
s = j(ncol(u2),ncol(u1),0);
do  i=1 to ncol(u1);
do  z=1 to ncol(u2);
    idx=loc(…);
s[z,i]=countn(idx);
end;
end;
print s;
```

Comment: Couple of hints.  First, you don't want to use COUNTN, but NCOL.  NCOL(matrix) works when a matrix is empty.  COUNTN does not.  See why?  Second, you want to use LOC to identify which rows of MATRIX match the current value of fruits and names.  To use a combination of two values on LOC, you use &&; so for example, loc(matrix[,1]="APPLES" && matrix[,2]="A") would identify the rows that are "APPLES" and "A" (none, of course, but that's okay).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. Since it is for a class, I will offer hints rather than provide a complete solution.

1) The first approach is to use the UNIQUE function and LOC function together. This so-called "UNIQUE-LOC technique" is very useful for computing with categories.  A one-dimensional example is shown in the article "[The UNIQUE-LOC trick](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/11/01/the-unique-loc-trick-a-real-treat/)."  I will leave it to you to generalize it to a cross-tab.

2) A second approach is to use the SORT and UNIQUEBY functions together. This second technique is described in the article "[An efficient alternative to the UNIQUE-LOC technique](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/11/07/an-efficient-alternative-to-the-unique-loc-technique/)."  Again, I will leave it to you to read the article and figure out how to apply it to your class project.

I could also tell you which solution is easier...but I'll let you make that determination instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Dear Rick, thank you for your answer. Still was not able to reach a final solution but I have some code which probably gets me a little bit closer. If you can help me out, perhaps with another tip I would be really grateful.

Comment: OK. My second hint is that UNIQUEBY is easier!  The UNIQUE/LOC solution requires a lot of bookkeeping.